# $\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{p\ge 0}\frac{m!n!p!}{(m+n+p+3)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate: $\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{p\ge 0}\frac {m!n!p!}{(m+n+p+3)!}$

my working :
Claim:$\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{k!}{(k+l)!}=\frac{1}{(l-1)((l-1)!)}$

proof:$\frac{k!}{(k+l)!}=\frac{1}{l-1}\left(\frac{k!}{(l+k-1)!}-\frac{(k+1)!}{(l+k)!}\right)$

$\implies\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{k!}{(k+l)!}=\frac{1}{(l-1)((l-1)!)}$

now $\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{p\ge 0}\frac {m!n!p!}{(m+n+p+3)!}=\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge 0}m!n!\sum_{p\ge 0}\frac {p!}{(m+n+p+3)!}$
$=\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge 0}m!n!\frac {1}{(m+n+2)((m+n+2)!)}$

Comment: Did you ever worked on ?$$\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac {m!n!}{(m+n+3)!}\\
\sum_{m\ge 0}\frac {m!}{(m+3)!}\\$$?

Comment: Equal to the following integral (but I don't see how to evaluate it): $$\iiint\limits_{\substack{x,y,z\geqslant 0\\x+y+z\leqslant 1}}\frac{dx\,dy\,dz}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}$$

Comment: Mathematica tells that the sum is equal to $$ S = -\frac{\pi^2}{2}\log 2 + \frac{13}{4}\zeta(3) \approx 0.4861407033. $$ I can reduce the sum to a single integral $$S = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(t)-\operatorname{Li}_2(1-t)}{t-\frac{1}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}t - 2\zeta(3), $$ but I have no good idea for further simplifying this one.

Comment: @SangchulLee integration by parts together with my comment below  the accepted answer should be enough to tackle your integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer, I can only reduce the sum to a single integral.

For any $d \ge 1$, let $\Delta_d$ be the simplex
$$\Delta_d = \{ (x_1,\ldots,x_d) \in [0,\infty)^d : x_1 + \cdots x_d \le 1 \}$$
The summands at hand can be represented as integrals over $\Delta_3$.

$$\frac{m!n!p!}{(m+n+p+3)!} = \int_{\Delta_3} x^m y^n z^p dxdydz$$

This leads to
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{S} \stackrel{def}{=} & \sum_{m,n,p \ge 0}\frac{m!n!p!}{(m+n+p+3)!}
= \int_{\Delta_3}\frac{dxdydz}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}\\
= &\int_{\Delta_2}  \left(\int_0^{1-y-z}\frac{dx}{1-x}\right) \frac{dydz}{(1-y)(1-z)}
\\
= & -\int_{\Delta_2} \frac{\log(y+z)}{(1-y)(1-z)} dydz\\
= & -\int_{\Delta_2} \left(\frac{1}{1-y} + \frac{1}{1-z}\right)\frac{\log(y+z) dydz}{2 - y - z}\\
= & -2\int_{\Delta_2} \frac{\log(y+z)dydz}{(1-y)(2-y-z)}
\end{align}$$
Change variable to $(y,\lambda) = (y,y+z)$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{S}
&= -2\int_0^1 \int_0^\lambda \frac{\log \lambda}{(1-y)(2-\lambda)} dy d\lambda
= 2\int_0^1 \frac{\log\lambda\log(1-\lambda)}{2-\lambda} d\lambda\\
&\approx 0.4861407
\end{align}
$$
This is as far as I can go.

Comment: I think the last integral can be evaluated by using the trick that $\log(1-\lambda)\log(\lambda)/2=\log^2(\lambda/(1-\lambda))-\log(1-\lambda)^2/2-\log^2(\lambda)/2$. For the first part use $q=\lambda/(1-\lambda)$ to transform it to something managable by contour methods. for part two and three plain series expansion of $(2-\lambda)^{-1}$ plus maybe a trilogarithm identity should be sufficent to find something along the lines @Sangchul Lee  mentinoned.